# Use a number sign instead of a slash - mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im having a domain and two variables. The first variable is seperated with a slash (/) - on the second variable i'm trying to use a number sign (#).

I'm working with mod_rewrite so i have this result, which dont work:

I first tried it with a # and then after some look ups, i found that the number sign is replaced to a %23.

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)%23(\d+)$ /index.php?id=$1&value=$2

**Example**:
www.domain.tld/index.php?id=123&value=5000 -> www.domain.tld/123#5000

Where's the problem? If I use on both variables for the seperating a slash, it works.

Comment: I wouldn't advise using a hash (number sign) for anything other than it's intention, pointing the browser to an anchor location on the page.

Comment: Anything after a `#` in a URL will not be sent to the server, as it denotes the "fragment" or "anchor" that the *client* (browser) should navigate to once the page has loaded. It would be possible to encode a `#` in a URL, but it will be fiddly, and you'd need a pretty good reason for it.